# How do you declare a global variable for MediaPlayer?

Tags: android, kotlin

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
...
  val mpOkay = MediaPlayer.create (this, R.raw.inordnung)
...
}
```

works but

```
val mpOkay = null
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
...
  mpOkay = MediaPlayer.create (this, R.raw.inordnung)
...
}
```

and

```
var mpOkay
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
...
  mpOkay = MediaPlayer.create (this, R.raw.inordnung)
...
}
```

don't.

Does kotlin want me to create a new Mediaplayer over and over and to waste memory?

Comment: That's invalid syntax. I suggest you read Kotlin syntax documentation first.

Comment: You do want to create a new one over and over. The `MediaPlayer` docs say as much. Holding onto the resources when your app is paused is a bad thing. You should be releasing it when paused. If anything, that's the opposite of wasting memory because it won't stick around when you're not using it, not to mention the save on other resources.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare the type of the variable to be able to assign a `MediaPlayer` to it, for example:

```
var mpOkay: MediaPlayer? = null
```

---

In the declaration

```
var mpOkay = null
```

`mpOkay` gets its type inferred to `Nothing?`, which means you won't be able to assign any value other than `null` to it.

---

And the declaration

```
var mpOkay
```

is simply not valid syntax, because this property has no declared or inferable type.

Comment: Good that works. Now I am trying to run it with `mpOkay.start()` and get a `only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type MediaPlayer`. EDIT: I fixed it with `mpOkay?.start()`

Comment: Yes, declaring a variable or property nullable will force you to check it for the possible `null` value when you use it. You should look at the official docs about [null safety](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls).

Answer (score 1):

Exactly for cases like `onCreate`, where you *are* going to initialize a variable to a non-null value before accessing it but for whatever reason can't do it in the constructor, Kotlin has

```
lateinit var mpOkay: MediaPlayer
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, you can use "by lazy" to set a val property (which won't require testing for null, `!!` or `?` to use).

```
val mp: MediaPlayer by lazy { MediaPlayer.create(context, resId)  }
```

This will run `MediaPlay.create()` only once on first access of `mp`.  Be sure that the `context` is valid before accessing `mp`.